# Python; Add header/footer for printout page(s) on existing Excel file without changing data

Tags: python, excel, header, openpyxl

I am trying to add a print header caption for all sheets of an existing Excel file. 
I wrote code as shown bellow, but it create new sheet and all data will be lost.

How can I add an header/footer for printout page of an exist excel file and  not change data?

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

def addExcelFile(locationPath, textAdd):
    
    for file in glob.glob(locationPath + '\\**\\*.xlsx', recursive=True):        
        errorFile = os.path.basename(file).split('/')[-1]
        print(errorFile[0:2])
        if (errorFile[0:2] != '~$'):
            print(file)
            xl = pd.ExcelFile(file, engine='openpyxl')

            # Open a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter')
            # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
            workbook  = writer.book
            listSheet = xl.sheet_names
            print(len(listSheet))
            # see all sheet names
            if(textAdd == 'LGE Confidential'):
                for i in range (0,len(listSheet)):
                    nameSheet = listSheet[i]
                    writer.sheets={nameSheet:workbook.add_worksheet()}
                    worksheet = writer.sheets[nameSheet]
                    # Set color for text :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colors?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 
                    # replace char FF -> K in start color code 
                    worksheet.set_header('&C&"Tahoma,Bold"&14&Kff0000' + textAdd)

            elif(textAdd == 'LGE Internal Use Only'):
                for i in range (0,len(listSheet)):
                    nameSheet = listSheet[i]
                    writer.sheets={nameSheet:workbook.add_worksheet()}
                    worksheet = writer.sheets[nameSheet]
                    # Set color for text :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colors?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 
                    # replace char FF -> K in start color code 
                    worksheet.set_header('&C&"Tahoma,Bold"&14&Ka9a9a9' + textAdd)

            # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
            writer.save()
            xl.close()
        else:
            print('File error: ', file, '. It will not be add header!')
```

Add an header/footer for printout page of an exist excel file and do not change data.

Comment: You are using xlsxwriter as the writer engine. Xlsxwriter only ever creates a new workbook, it cannot read existing workbooks so saving the writer as is will overwrite the existing workbook with the new created workbook which seems will only consist of the original sheets and no data.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be doing more than what is needed for your required result.
You just want to add Headers to the sheets in the workbooks. There is no need to use Pandas and Xlwriters for that, just use Openpyxl and update each sheet.
Also you have duplication in your code, try to avoid repeating code if the same code segment can be used for multiple applications. The section `if(textAdd == 'LGE Confidential'):` etc duplicates around 4 lines unnecessarily.

With Openpyxl you can set the Header (and Footer) as one of three sections left, center and right, and allows different setting for first and odd/even pages. In the example I have used 'center' section and included all pages so you can change to what suits.

As far as I can see for what you want the following code sample should do what you need. I have hard set the 'textAdd' string so the code is runnable, change between each for testing.

```
import openpyxl
import glob
import os


def addExcelFile(textAdd, workbook):

        ### Set the colour for the header, only two variations based on the text. Grey can be the
        ### default colour which is set and only changed if the text is 'LGE Confidential'
        head_color = 'a9a9a9'  # Default to Grey
        if textAdd == 'LGE Confidential':
            head_color = 'ff0000'  # Change to RED if the text is 'LGE Confidential'

        ### Create the Header from the default style, colour and text
        headertext = '&C&"Tahoma,Bold"&14&K' + head_color + textAdd

        ### Add the header as needed
        for sheet in workbook.worksheets:
            sheet.firstHeader.center.text = headertext
            sheet.oddHeader.center.text = headertext
            sheet.evenHeader.center.text = headertext



locationPath = '<path>'
### Header text (textAdd). Hard set here for code runability
ta = 'LGE Confidential'
# ta = 'LGE Internal Use Only'

for file in glob.glob(locationPath + '\\**\\*.xlsx', recursive=True):
    errorFile = os.path.basename(file).split('/')[-1]
    print(errorFile[0:2])
    if errorFile[0:2] != '~$':
        print(file)

    ### Open the workbook with Openpyxl
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

    ### Call function to add Header to workbook sheets
    addExcelFile(ta, wb)

    ### Save updated workbook 
    wb.save(file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guide. I'll try it